# Making a countdown "Pie" Clock using rotating images

Tags: android, image, time, clock, countdown

what i wish to make is a pie type clock that counts time from 1 minute to 0.
My question is how do i add images or remove them using a script to a layout view and make them rotate at the  center of the layout view, depending on a countdown.

What would be the best approach for it? where do i start? and what would i need to read about to make it?

Thanks in advance :]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is that you can create all the images you need and use CountDownTimer to relate to each image. 
I do not know what you are exactly trying to do but creating an animation (flash) and putting it into your application may work as long as you have the timing done correctly.

For an analog clock, this is what I use:

```
public void CDT() {
//CHANGE 31000 TO WHATEVER YOU WANT. FOR 60 SEC, I WOULD USE 60000 OR 61000
new CountDownTimer(31000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
//THIS MAKES IT LOOK NICER WHEN IT COUNTS DOWN (eg. :09 instead of :9)
        if(millisUntilFinished < 10000) {
            textTimer.setText(":0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
        else {
            textTimer.setText(":" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
        }
    public void onFinish() {
        textTimer.setText(":00");
        new AlertDialog.Builder(SplitEmUpBeta2Activity.this)
        .setTitle("TEXT").setMessage("TEXT")
        .setNeutralButton("TEXT", null);
        .show();
        }
    }
.start();
}
```

If you really want to create the "Pie" clock, you need to set onTick to replace the image of the clock with the appropriate one (remove the old and add the new). For example:

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    if(millisUntilFinished == 60000) {
        //REPLACE IMAGE (REMOVE OLD AND REPLACE WITH NEW)
        }
    // AND SO ON UNTIL YOU FINISH ALL THE IMAGES
}
```

Comment: That will work for the count down, thanks.  i want to place a canvas image, and rotate accroding to the time count down, that's possible right?,

Comment: Yes it is possible but you are going to have to find some way to relate each count to each image as I have mentioned in my answer. You could have the pie image and the pointer image separate so only the pointer image moves and rotates.